# Django-mptt admin get child categories

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-mptt

I have next models in my Django project:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    title_of_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Subcategory', default='')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True,
                            default='',
                            verbose_name='Category')
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Category', default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Title of product', default='')
```

Also admin:

```
class CategoryAdmin(DjangoMpttAdmin):
    list_display = ('title_of_category',)
    list_filter = ('title_of_category',)

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', )
```

I would like to show in my admin panel only child category(category without children) in ForeignKey. 
How can I filter category in admin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking but check out this post as it may help.
[Changing name of Foreign Key items at admin page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988897/changing-name-of-foreign-key-items-at-admin-page-in-django/46989479#46989479)